# Nature of an improper integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I want to study the convergence of this integral at 0:
$$
\int_0^{1}\frac{e^{\frac 1 t}}{\sqrt{t(1+t^2)}}\;dt.
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int_{\varepsilon}^{1}\frac{e^{1/t}}{\sqrt{t(1+t^2)}}\,dt = \int_{1}^{1/\varepsilon}\frac{e^t}{\sqrt{t(1+t^2)}}\,dt$$
and the exponential function grows too fast to make the RHS converging as $\varepsilon\to 0^+$.

For instance, since $t+t^3<e^{6t/5}$ on $[1,+\infty)$,

$$\int_{1}^{1/\varepsilon}\frac{e^t}{\sqrt{t(1+t^2)}}\,dt \geq \int_{1}^{1/\varepsilon}e^{2t/5}\,dt = \frac{5}{2}\left(\exp\frac{2}{5\varepsilon}-\exp\frac{2}{5}\right).$$

Comment: OK for the change of variable, but, excuse me, I did not understood the second part of your answer. Can you please give me some details (a comparaison with the Riemann integral for example?). Thanks.

Comment: @SAKLY: explanation added.